# How to find $f^{-1}(22)$ with $f(x,y) = 15x+55y$ for integer $x,y$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I don't even know how to get the inverse of this function

The complete function is described as the following:
$f:\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x,y)=15x+55y$

Comment: You want to solve $15x+55y=22$? That's a linear equation. What's is the problem?

Comment: I guess there's an infinite number of solutions? @Fakemistake

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: "*how to get the inverse of this function*"  Inverse *functions* only exist when the original function is bijective.  This is clearly not bijective... It is neither injective (*since $f(55,0)=15\cdot 55 + 55\cdot 0$ is equal to $f(0,15)=15\cdot 0 + 55\cdot 15$ for instance so $f^{-1}(55\cdot 15)$ is ambiguous*) nor is it surjective (*since there exist no integers $x,y$ such that $f(x,y)=1$ for instance since $15x+55y$ is always a multiple of $5$*).

Comment: @ BenjaminWang, @Fakemistake for some numbers there are infinitely many solutions here.  For other numbers there are *zero* solutions.  Note that the domain and codomain here were specified to be pairs of integers and integers respectively.  There do not exist integers $x,y$ such that $15x+55y=22$.  The left hand side is a multiple of $5$.  The right hand side is not.

Comment: @JMoravitz That's my problem, I had to decide if it was injective and surjective, and it is neither, yet the following task is to find f^-1(22), and the next one is to find f^-1(38) so I'm sure I must be missing something??

Comment: If you were to treat $f^{-1}$ as instead the inverse **relation** rather than the inverse *function*, the answers for both would be $\emptyset$, i.e. that no such pairs of integers $x,y$ exist, again... because neither $22$ nor $38$ are multiples of $5$ which happens to be $\gcd(15,55)$

Comment: Thank you, it probably did mean the inverse relation instead of function, I'll just leave the answer for both as Ø. What confused me was the usage of f^-1 which made me think I was supposed to find an inverse of the function and I was just lost

Comment: Just to be clear, given any function $f : A \to B$, and given any $b \in B$, the notation $f^{-1}(b)$ represents the *subset* of $A$ given by the formula $$f^{-1}(b) = \{a \in A \mid f(a)=b\}$$ So in your case, where $f : \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z$ is given by $f(x,y)=15x+55y$, you get $$f^{-1}(22)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb Z^2 \mid 15 x + 55 y = 22\}$$

Comment: @LeeMosher Just to be clear, the definition you give is for the inverse *relation* $f^{-1}$, not for the inverse *function* $f^{-1}$.  They both receive the same symbol and agree when the inverse function actually exists, however they are distinct definitions.  It is just as correct to say here that $f^{-1}$ doesn't exist when referring to the inverse *function*.  It is this distinction which was the cause of the confusion here and your giving the definition you gave without clarifying the distinction perpetuates the confusion.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Here we shall have to agree to disagree. One meaning of the $f^{-1}$ notation is more general than the other, a set theoretic point that would have helped the questioner up front, that you alluded to in your "If you were to treat..." comment, and that I wanted to enchance by writing out explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation) says that $ax+by=c$
has solutions if and only if $c$ is a multiple of $\text{GCD}(a,b)$.

$$15 x+55 y=22$$
has no integer solutions because $\text{GCD}(15,25)=5$ but $5$ doesn't divide $22$.

Therefore $f(x,y)$ has no inverse at $22$.